# Eclipse or other utility to cleanup warnings for "Redundant specification of type arguments"?

Tags: eclipse, java-7

I am part of a massive project that just tweaked its Eclipse settings for Java 1.7

We are getting thousands of these warnings:

> Redundant specification of type arguments

For situations where something like this:

```
HashMap<String,String> hm = new HashMap<String,String>();
```

Should be rewritten as something like this:

```
HashMap<String,String> hm = new HashMap<>();
```

Is there an Eclipse utility, or any other utility that will automatically clean these situations up?

We are using Eclipse 3.8, but will be migrating in about 3 months to the SWT 4 and a more up to date copy of Eclipse.

Answer (score 2):

Fix found [here](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=351956):

> In Luna (4.4), the multi-fix in the whole file works via Quick Fix hover or via Ctrl+1 popup and then using Ctrl+Enter. To apply the fix to a whole project, you can:
>   - select the problem in the Problems view
>   - select the whole project so that the Problems view shows problems from all selected resources
>   - activate the Problems view again and use Ctrl+1 or context menu > Quick Fix
>   - select the right fix, click Select All, and click Finish

Comment: Just checked it out - works nicely, I'll have to add this to my Eclipse cheatseet!

Comment: I'm stuck with Eclipse 3.8 for another 3 months.   If nobody suggests something automagic I can do with my current version of Eclipse I will accept this as the answer.  Thank You!!!!